# vba insert array formula from range to end row?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to insert an array formula down a column from row 10 onwards:

```
Sub Check()
ActiveSheet.Range("L10").End(xlUp).Row.FormulaArray = "=IF(J10<>"",INDEX(Data!B:B,MATCH(1,(Home!H10=Data!C:C)*(Home!I10=Data!D:D)*(Home!J10=Data!E:E),0)),INDEX(Data!B:B,MATCH(1,(Home!H10=Data!C:C)*(Home!I10=Data!D:D)*(K10=Data!F:F),0)))"
End Sub
```

For some reason this doesn't work and i get a object required error.
I also want each cell refernce to go down with each row. I'm new to vba so apologies if my code is not great, but if someone could please point me in the right direction i'd really appreciate it?

Thanks

Comment: If you want people to recreate you should highlight what sheets are referenced in your formula.  I can see `Data` and `Home` so far.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the error is the `""` to provide double quotes to the formula you need to use `""""` instead.

Then you would enter the formula into L10 this way:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("L10").FormulaArray = "=IF(J10<>"""",INDEX(Data!B:B,MATCH(1,(Home!H10=Data!C:C)*(Home!I10=Data!D:D)*(Home!J10=Data!E:E),0)),INDEX(Data!B:B,MATCH(1,(Home!H10=Data!C:C)*(Home!I10=Data!D:D)*(K10=Data!F:F),0)))"
```

Then to fill the rows below use Range.AutoFill

```
ActiveSheet.Range("L10").AutoFill .Range("L10:l100")
```

Where L10:L100 is the range into which the formula is to be placed.

So:

```
Sub Check()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = ActiveSheet
With sht
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("L10").FormulaArray = "=IF(J10<>"""",INDEX(Data!B:B,MATCH(1,(Home!H10=Data!C:C)*(Home!I10=Data!D:D)*(Home!J10=Data!E:E),0)),INDEX(Data!B:B,MATCH(1,(Home!H10=Data!C:C)*(Home!I10=Data!D:D)*(K10=Data!F:F),0)))"
    .Range("L10").AutoFill ActiveSheet.Range("L10:L" & lastrow)
End With

End Sub
```

**NOTE**

As stated in the comments, all the full column references to the data set on Data need to also be changed to reference only the data.

Array formulas will iterate and calculate the entire reference.  So each Formula will do over 8 million calculations.  Multiply that by how many times the formula is entered and you can see how this will impact the calculation times and might even crash your excel.

Comment: i need this formula to be inserted to more than 100 rows though. I need this to be inserted down the entire column of L

Comment: @Bing.Wong you will crash Excel.  That many array formulas that refer to full column references like you have will cause huge delays in computations.  You need to limit all the references and the number of entries to only what is in the referenced data set and the actual number of data point in column J.

Comment: ok point taken. Is there a way i can insert these formulas down to the last used row then please? E.G. Last used row from column A for instance.

Comment: Yo need to do more than that.  If your data set  on Data is not over 1 million lines you need to adjust your formula to only the extents of that data.